# Hide the Fields audited list in sugarcrm to the regular user

Tags: php, sugarcrm

How can we hide the list of fields audited to the regular user,but to admin the list of audited fields are need to visible,
the following line need to hide for the regular user and only admin be able to see the below line
Fields audited in this module: name, title, etc

I am using sugarcrm ce 6.5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm understanding your question as "when a Regular User views the Audit history, he or she should not see the list of fields that are audited. System Administrators can still see this list. All Users should still see the actual audit/history table." If that's correct, here is my advice:

The list (and popup itself) is handled and generated in `modules/Audit/Popup_picker.php` so you would start by reviewing the code there.

It seems to me that the two lines below are responsible for displaying this output:

1. `echo $start_tag.translate('LBL_AUDITED_FIELDS', 'Audit').$fields.$end_tag;` (on/around line 139)
2. `echo $start_tag.translate('LBL_AUDITED_FIELDS', 'Audit').$end_tag;` (on/around line 143)

With that code found, I would copy the file `modules/Audit/Popup_picker.php` to `custom/modules/Audit/Popup_picker.php` and make adjustments to add a check like `if(is_admin($GLOBALS['current_user'])` into the code. If you used this as an extra condition, you might get something like the following, note that my changes are annotated by a <-- in the PHP comment, and that I cleaned up some indentation and white space):

```
if($field_count > 0 && is_admin($GLOBALS['current_user'])) // <-- Added Admin-Check Condition
{
    $index = 0;
    foreach($audited_fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $index++;
        $vname = ''; 

        if(isset($value['vname']))
            $vname = $value['vname'];
        else if(isset($value['label']))
            $vname = $value['label'];

        $fields .= str_replace(':', '', translate($vname, $focus->module_dir));

        if($index < $field_count)
        {   
            $fields .= ", ";
        }   
    }

    echo $start_tag.translate('LBL_AUDITED_FIELDS', 'Audit').$fields.$end_tag;
} elseif(is_admin($GLOBALS['current_user'])) { // <-- changed ELSE to ELSEIF and added Admin-Check Condition
    echo $start_tag.translate('LBL_AUDITED_FIELDS', 'Audit').$end_tag;
} else { // added new ELSE statement
    echo $start_tag.$end_tag; // <-- Regular users shouldn't see the message at all so render the empty table
}
```

I haven't ran and tested this code but I expect that this will give you a good strategy to dig in and create the customization yourself.

Comment: this only the solution I expected. i will dig into it today itself.. 
Thanks a lot. 
Naren

Comment: It works perfect..except minor bug missing ) in if else if statement.. 
thanks

Comment: Not bad for a quick draft then -- added missing paren. Glad it worked.

Comment: please add the same paren on line one(if statement also).. thanks Naren

Comment: HI
one thing want to clarify on this thing. It works only on non upgrade safe code(Main modules), if i tried to move this code to custom(upgrade safe code) it was not working(not affects)..is this a bug in my code or what?
can you plz clarify when you get a chance, its not an urgent one.

thanks 
Naren